# Is copying automatically prohibited in classes derived from classed derived from Boost noncopyable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, noncopyable

For example:

```
class Foo : boost::noncopyable
{
    // ...
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    // ...
};
```

Is `Bar` non-copyable?

Comment: +1 because this is a very well-formed question. That I think the answer is a bit obvious is not relevant. :)

Comment: I had to think about it for a bit before it became apparent. I was surprised that no one ever asked this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default it is non-copyable, unless you create a custom copy-constructor and avoid calling a base copy-constructor there.

See also [Explicitly-defaulted and deleted special member functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions) introduced in C++11. Even though making a copy constructor/operator private solves the problem, the compiler generates a diagnostic message that is far from pretty and obvious, so deleted copy constructors/operators are there in C++11 to solve this problem.

Comment: ..and that would almost certainly be "broken".

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes :-) But still possible, hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the derived class doesn't have custom copy-constructor which avoids calling the noncopyable copy-constructor, then yes. At all level, all derived classes of `boost::noncopyable` would be non-copyable. As object of derived class also contains the subobject of `boost::noncopyable` which is `non-copyable`, that means no derived class can be copyable without base-class being copyable,

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` derives from `boost::noncopyable` (even though it's not a direct inheritance), so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it were copyable then all base classes must be copyable, but boost::noncopyable is non-copyable

Comment: "if it [were] copyable then all derived classes must be copyable" <-- not so. Consider `struct Bar : struct Foo, boost::noncopyable {};`. `Foo` is copyable (say), but `Bar` is not.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, I've mixed up `base` and `derived` - fixed now